LoadRunner TrueClient Copy n by m cells from excel and paste it to the editable grid on the browser
I'm using the TrueClient protocol to generate the Vugen script.

We have a Dynamics 365 web app with an editable grid, where we can directly copy and paste Excel cells.

Manually I can copy and paste the 6x10 rows from Excel and past them at 0,0 position to the editable grid on the browser and it pastes the values to the corresponding cells on the browsers perfectly.
I have to generate the script with the scenario to copy 6 rows and 10 columns from the Excel available in the local directory and paste it to the editable grid on position 1st row 1st column (which also has 6 rows and 10 columns).
I'm unable to do that, does anyone have ever tried it?
Any input is much appreciated.

Truclient is browser only.  As you wish to run excel, think architecturally. You will need the following for load

Single OS instance per virtual user.  This can be a virtual machine or it can be Citrix or Remote Desktop/terminal Services
Excel and Browser installed on OS instance
If Citrix or RDS, you will need the appropriate virtual user type, then that virtual user will operate the OS instance, starting excel and the browser, then affecting the copy and paste between the apps
If Virtual Machine, OS instance, then you will need a graphical virtual user (quicktest pro) to operate the virtual user to start excel, the browser, then affect a copy and paste.

This answer leverages a foundation skill for all performance testers, application architecture.  You may need some mentoring in this area.
